# What header should i use for plist to view in browser no Download?

Tags: php, plist

what header should i use for plist to view in browser no Download?
i used

> header('Content-Type: text/x-generic');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the plain text mime type `text/plain`.

Comment: thanks one more question when i want to edit plist file by file_get_contents and str_replace and use readfile it has an error failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: @mamrezo I would suggest starting another question for that.